# Compare version numbers without using split function

Tags: c#, string, compare, version, versioning

How do I compare version numbers?

For instance:

x = 1.23.56.1487.5

y = 1.24.55.487.2

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: a version with 5 parts? If you were using the typical 4 part version you could use the System.Version class, which includes methods to compare versions and parse the version string

Comment: What are the types of x and y?

Comment: Whenever someone says "Don't use `X`, `Y` or `Z`", it always makes me wonder why. Why do you not want to use the `split` function? The `split` function seems like a good way to do this if you aren't going to use the `System.Version` class.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Can you use the `Version` class?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version

It has an `IComparable` interface.  Be aware this won't work with a 5-part version string like you've shown (is that really your version string?).  Assuming your inputs are strings, here's a working sample with the normal .NET 4-part version string:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string v1 = "1.23.56.1487";
        string v2 = "1.24.55.487";

        var version1 = new Version(v1);
        var version2 = new Version(v2);

        var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
        if (result > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("version1 is greater");
        else if (result < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("version2 is greater");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("versions are equal");
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: Only if the version consists from 2-4 parts

Comment: @dev_Boston only one exception...just do with these values v1=1.0001 and v2=1.1 .it gives me equal.

Comment: Yes, the version strings are not decimal strings, and prepending zeroes to a portion of the version number is irrelevant.  In other words, "00001" is equal to "1" in the 2nd part of the version string.

Comment: You can compare more readably as `Version.Parse(v1) < Version.Parse(v2)`, because `operator >(Version v1, Version v2)` is implemented.

Comment: Be aware that Version.Parse("6.0.0") is less than (<) Version.Parse("6.0.0.0") (i.e. are NOT equal).
`Debug.Assert(new Version("6.0.0") < new Version("6.0.0.0"));`

Answer (score 14):

If you can live with the major.minor.build.revision scheme you could use the .Net [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class. Otherwise you'd have to implement some kind of parsing from left to right and continuing until you have a difference or return that two versions are equal.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @JohnD 's answer there might be a need to compare only partial version numbers without using Split('.') or other string <-> int conversion bloat. I've just written an extension method CompareTo with 1 additional argument - number of significant parts of version number to compare (between 1 and 4).

```
public static class VersionExtensions
{
    public static int CompareTo(this Version version, Version otherVersion, int significantParts)
    {
        if(version == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("version");
        }
        if(otherVersion == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if(version.Major != otherVersion.Major && significantParts >= 1)
            if(version.Major > otherVersion.Major)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        if(version.Minor != otherVersion.Minor && significantParts >= 2)
            if(version.Minor > otherVersion.Minor)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        if(version.Build != otherVersion.Build && significantParts >= 3)
            if(version.Build > otherVersion.Build)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        if(version.Revision != otherVersion.Revision && significantParts >= 4)
            if(version.Revision > otherVersion.Revision)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public int compareVersion(string Version1,string Version2)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([\d]+)");
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection m1 = regex.Matches(Version1);
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection m2 = regex.Matches(Version2);
        int min = Math.Min(m1.Count,m2.Count);
        for(int i=0; i<min;i++)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(m1[i].Value)>Convert.ToInt32(m2[i].Value))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if(Convert.ToInt32(m1[i].Value)<Convert.ToInt32(m2[i].Value))
            {
                return -1;
            }               
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Beware that this would return equals for `compareVersion("1.3", "1.3.1")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine.  I needed to compare some wacky version strings like "3.2.1.7650.b40" versus "3.10.1" so I couldn't use the VersionInfo object as suggested above.
This is quick and dirty so ding me for style.  I did also provide a short function to test it.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test_CompareVersionStrings();
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two version strings, e.g.  "3.2.1.0.b40" and "3.10.1.a".
    /// V1 and V2 can have different number of components.
    /// Components must be delimited by dot.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This doesn't do any null/empty checks so please don't pass dumb parameters
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="v1"></param>
    /// <param name="v2"></param>
    /// <returns>
    /// -1 if v1 is lower version number than v2,
    /// 0 if v1 == v2,
    /// 1 if v1 is higher version number than v2,
    /// -1000 if we couldn't figure it out (something went wrong)
    /// </returns>
    private static int CompareVersionStrings(string v1, string v2)
    {
        int rc = -1000;

        v1 = v1.ToLower();
        v2 = v2.ToLower();

        if (v1 == v2)
            return 0;

        string[] v1parts = v1.Split('.');
        string[] v2parts = v2.Split('.');

        for (int i = 0; i < v1parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (v2parts.Length < i+1)
                break; // we're done here
            
            string v1Token = v1parts[i];
            string v2Token = v2parts[i];
            
            int x;
            bool v1Numeric = int.TryParse(v1Token, out x);
            bool v2Numeric = int.TryParse(v2Token, out x);
            
            // handle scenario {"2" versus "20"} by prepending zeroes, e.g. it would become {"02" versus "20"}
            if (v1Numeric && v2Numeric) {
                while (v1Token.Length < v2Token.Length)
                    v1Token = "0" + v1Token;
                while (v2Token.Length < v1Token.Length)
                    v2Token = "0" + v2Token;
            }

            rc = String.Compare(v1Token, v2Token, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            //Console.WriteLine("v1Token=" + v1Token + " v2Token=" + v2Token + " rc=" + rc);
            if (rc != 0)
                break;
        }

        if (rc == 0)
        {
            // catch this scenario: v1="1.0.1" v2="1.0"
            if (v1parts.Length > v2parts.Length)
                rc = 1; // v1 is higher version than v2
            // catch this scenario: v1="1.0" v2="1.0.1"
            else if (v2parts.Length > v1parts.Length)
                rc = -1; // v1 is lower version than v2
        }

        if (rc == 0 || rc == -1000)
            return rc;
        else
            return rc < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }
    
    private static int _CompareVersionStrings(string v1, string v2)
    {
        int rc = CompareVersionStrings(v1, v2);
        Console.WriteLine("Compare v1: " + v1 + "  v2: " + v2 + "  result: " + rc);
        return rc;
    }

    // for debugging
    private static void Test_CompareVersionStrings()
    {
        bool allPass = true;

        // should be equal
        allPass &= (0 == _CompareVersionStrings("1", "1"));
        allPass &= (0 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.1", "1.1"));
        allPass &= (0 == _CompareVersionStrings("3.3.a20", "3.3.A20"));

        // v1 should be lower
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1", "2"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.0", "1.0.1"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.0", "1.1"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.0.0.3", "1.1"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.4b"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.4.b"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.8.0", "20.0.0.0"));
        allPass &= (-1 == _CompareVersionStrings("5.6.0.788.2", "20.0.0.0"));

        // v1 should be higher
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("2", "1"));
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.0.1", "1.0"));
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.1", "1.0"));
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.1", "1.0.0.3"));
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.2.3.4b", "1.2.3.4"));
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("1.2.3.4.b", "1.2.3.4")); 
        allPass &= (1 == _CompareVersionStrings("20.0.0.0", "5.6.0.788.2"));

        Console.WriteLine("allPass = " + allPass.ToString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Wrong. See ("1.8.0","20.0.0.0") = -1 and ("5.6.0.788.2","20.0.0.0") = 1

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I corrected it above and also created a dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ehGhJT

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are not allowed to use the compare-method of the Version directly (e.g. in a client-server scenario), another approach is to extract a long number from the version and then compare the numbers with each other.
However, the number needs to have the following format: Two digits for Major, Minor and Revision and four for Build.

How to extract the version number:

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

long newVersion = version.Major * 1000000000L + 
                   version.Minor * 1000000L + 
                   version.Build * 1000L + 
                   version.Revision;
```

And then somewhere else you can just compare:

```
if(newVersion > installedVersion)
{
  //update code
}
```

Note: the installedVersion is a previously extracted long number

Comment: To give all digits 3 places, the code should actually be : "version.Major * 1000000000L +  version.Minor * 1000000L + version.Build * 1000L + version.Revision"

Comment: @StefHeyenrath That is correct, feel free to adjust the above code to your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

I found this algoritm on internet seems to work well.

```
//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-version-numbers/amp/

static int versionCompare(string v1, string v2)
    {
        // vnum stores each numeric
    
        // part of version
    
        int vnum1 = 0, vnum2 = 0;
    
        // loop until both string are
        // processed
    
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; (i < v1.Length || j < v2.Length);)
    
        {
            // storing numeric part of
            // version 1 in vnum1
            while (i < v1.Length && v1[i] != '.')
            {
    
                vnum1 = vnum1 * 10 + (v1[i] - '0');
    
                i++;
            }
            // storing numeric part of
    
            // version 2 in vnum2
    
            while (j < v2.Length && v2[j] != '.')
            {
                vnum2 = vnum2 * 10 + (v2[j] - '0');
                j++;
            }
            if (vnum1 > vnum2)
                return 1;
    
            if (vnum2 > vnum1)
                return -1;
    
            // if equal, reset variables and
    
            // go for next numeric part
            vnum1 = vnum2 = 0;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```