# C#.NET type for multiple point decimal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, type-conversion, .net-4.5

I have come across an issue that I can't seem to find any answers for. I have a number as a string in the format "5.2.3" what format would I convert this into to be able to use the greater than and less than operators in C#? I have tried the following which errors:

```
Decimal version = Decimal.Parse(strVersion);
if (version < Decimal.Parse("5.2.4"))
{
     // Do something
}
```

The decimal type which essentially this number is gives me the error "Invalid Format Exception"?

Comment: That is not a valid number. What do you intend this number to be stored as?

Comment: This is a version code for an application and I need to check if the version is less than that which I specify in an "if" statement?

Comment: Then see answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you want to compare the versions.

You can use [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that

Try below sample code as answered here [Compare version numbers without using split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568147/compare-version-numbers-without-using-split-function:-)

```
string v1 = "1.23.56.1487";
        string v2 = "1.24.55.487";

        var version1 = new Version(v1);
        var version2 = new Version(v2);

        var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
        if (result > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("version1 is greater");
        else if (result < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("version2 is greater");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("versions are equal");
        return;
```

Comment: akho divas ahiya j padiyo hoy che ?

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Your variable name seems to indicate that you're looking at a version number anyway, and the class provides comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

use Version

```
string n1 = "5.2.4";
string n2 = "5.3.4";

Version v1 = new Version(n1);
Version v2 = new Version(n2);

int result = v1.CompareTo(v2);

if (result > 0)
{
    //greater than v1
}
else if (result < 0)
{
    //2 is greater
}
else
{
    //they are equal
}
```