# How can I check github releases in c#?

Tags: c#, api, github, release, octokit.net

Something like this.

```
void UpdateCheck()
{
    if (GithubApi.GetCurrentRelease().Version > CurrentVersion)
}
```

How can I do this?

I found some API, https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net

but I can't find this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Octokit.net you should be able to get started using [this example](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/releases.md#get-all) from the documentation:

> ### Get All
>
> To retrieve all releases for a repository:
>
> ```
> var releases = client.Release.GetAll("octokit", "octokit.net");
> var latest = releases[0];
> Console.WriteLine(
>     "The latest release is tagged at {0} and is named {1}", 
>     latest.TagName, 
>     latest.Name);
> ```

Alternatively, you could [use the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) directly:

> ### List releases for a repository
>
> Information about published releases are available to everyone. Only users with push access will receive listings for draft releases.
>
> ```
> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I updated Chris code with the latest changes to octokit.net as the documentation by Octokit is a bit unclear. The code will **not** work without the await/async keywords.

```
using System;
using Octokit;

private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CheckGitHubNewerVersion()
{
    //Get all releases from GitHub
    //Source: https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/
    GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("SomeName"));
    IReadOnlyList<Release> releases = await client.Repository.Release.GetAll("Username", "Repository");
    
    //Setup the versions
    Version latestGitHubVersion = new Version(releases[0].TagName);
    Version localVersion = new Version("X.X.X"); //Replace this with your local version. 
                                                 //Only tested with numeric values.
    
    //Compare the Versions
    //Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568147/compare-version-numbers-without-using-split-function
    int versionComparison = localVersion.CompareTo(latestGitHubVersion);
    if (versionComparison < 0)
    {
        //The version on GitHub is more up to date than this local release.
    }
    else if (versionComparison > 0)
    {
        //This local version is greater than the release version on GitHub.
    }
    else
    {
        //This local Version and the Version on GitHub are equal.
    }
 }
```

Here is the NuGet

```
Install-Package Octokit
```

Comment: Note: if TagName includes more than just dot-separated numbers like 'v1.0.0' or '3.10.3-rc2', you can't construct Version objects unless you remove the other characters. Also note that `Version("1.0.0") < Version("1.0.0.0")` for some reason.