# Comparing Version values with C# Expression Trees

Tags: c#, tree, comparison, expression, version

I am trying to use C# Expression Trees for a rule engine and ran into an issue with Version comparison.
I would like the expression to do something like

Version < "4.5.1"

but C# Expressions consider the version value as string and do not allow lessthan operator on it. I could create a custom method for this comparison by pre-identifying the string value as a Version number (RegEx comparison) but I was hoping to find a way where C# Expression can identify is directly.

I was not able to find any documentation or examples on how I can create an Expression that could compare versions.

Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: Version objects are `IComparable` so you can call [Version.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to it. [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568147/compare-version-numbers-without-using-split-function)

Comment: As expressions you can do  somthing like:
`var compareVersion = typeof(Version).GetMethod("CompareTo", new Type[] { typeof(Version) });
  var versionCtor = typeof(Version).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
  
  var versionVariable = Expression.Constant(new Version(v1), typeof(Version));  
  var stringVariable = Expression.Constant(v2, typeof(string));
  var comparisonExpression = Expression.Call(versionVariable, compareVersion, Expression.New(versionCtor, stringVariable));
  var comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(comparisonExpression).Compile(); `