# Comparing Mozilla Firefox version using C#

Tags: c#, compare

I want to compare Mozilla firefox version. So, I'm getting Mozilla version as a string. Like **"50.0.2"**.
So, I'm trying to convert that **string** into **float** type using following program, but I'm getting following an error.

> Input string was not in a correct format

**Code :**

```
float f = float.Parse(MozillaVersion, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); 
if (f >= 48.0) // Here, MozillaVersion = "50.0.2"
{
    // code here
}
else
{
    // code here
}
```

I'm newbie in C#. So, someone help me. Is there any way to compare mozilla version?

Comment: Can you mention the value you are getting in `MozillaVersion`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare version numbers without using split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568147/compare-version-numbers-without-using-split-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Version.Parse-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net you should use for this:

```
Version v = Version.Parse("50.0.2");

if (v.Major >= 48) {
}
```